# JavaScript - How to use variable as key?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I am very new to JavaScript and read some questions about the topic but none of them gave me a solution to my problem.

I want to change user data in Active Directory, so I use ldapjs. There is a method to change a property of a user.

```
   client.modify(
          user['dn'],
          [new ldap.Change({
              operation: 'replace',
              modification: {
                _var_: u['st']
              }})]);
```

When I know the key (`_var_`)I want to set, this works perfectly. But I got an object that contains any to be changed key-value pairs. Something like `u = { sn: 'test',  l: 'test', st: 'test'};` Now I want to iterate over all properties of `u` and modify the related properties of `user` (in AD). Is there a way to set the `_var_` key in `modification` dynamically to fit the actual key of `u` (sn, l, st)?

Comment: what does `_var_` contain in this case?

Comment: @zola _var_ should be 'sn' in the first iteration 'l' in the second, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ? Provided that `_var_` contains a string.

```
var modification = {};
modification[_var_]=u['st'];
client.modify(
      user['dn'],
      [new ldap.Change({
          operation: 'replace',
          modification: modification})]);
```

So using your `u` object:

```
for(var k in u){
    modification[k]=u[k];
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbec14q/).

Comment: why do I use 'modification: modification'? wouldn't it work with just 'modification'?

Comment: The first 'modification' is the key in your object, the second is the variable you created 2 lines above.

Comment: wouldn't it just try to change a field called 'modification' in AD-user?

Comment: As far as I understand the [changeJS API](http://ldapjs.org/client.html#change), no.

Comment: I'm asking because I tried to use the modify function inside of  Object.keys(u).forEach(function(val) { } with val as 'modification'. As I log it, val changes fine to each property name but modify throws NoSuchAttributeError

Comment: oh - my failure. Sorry. I didn't set the modification property. Thank you.

Comment: _wouldn't it work with just 'modification'?_- it would depending on your nodejs version. It's new [ES6 shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). E.g.: `let a = 5; let b = {a};`, `b` is `{a:5}` now. Works fine on my nodejs 7.10.1